# setOnFocusChangeListener / onFocusChange not working in Immersive Mode

Tags: android, android-edittext, onfocus

So I have some EditTexts in my app and have built a custom KeyboardView that shows inside my activity that can show/allow typing/switch fields by FOCUS_FORWARDing while the app is in immersive mode. Unfortunately though I cannot get the scrollview to scroll to not hide the EditText while editing is going on. Does anyone know why the following code will not work while in immersive mode?

```
myEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                //do stuff now that in focus
            }
        }
    });
```

**TL;DR** - Can you call onFocusChange while in immersive mode on Android?